# The SCHEMABINDING option is supported only for natively compiled stored procedures, and is required for those stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a MS SQL Server 2014 running 2008 compabability mode, and a stored procedure is throwing the following error message:

```
Msg 10796, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_history_set, Line 16
The SCHEMABINDING option is supported only for natively compiled stored procedures, and is required for those stored procedures.
```

Unfortunately the stored procedure is encrypted so I can not access the source code.

When I google the error message, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133184(v=sql.120).aspx) is all I get.

Server properties:

Product - SQL Server Standard (64-bit)

OS - Microsoft Windows NT 6.3

Platform - NT x64

Version - 12.0.4213.0

Is there anything I can do to fix the error, though the SP is encrypted? Is the error due to some setting on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can not say why, but this issue was resolved by dropping and re-creating the procedure after getting access to the source code of the procedure.